# Как вывести строки из своей таблицы с пагинацией, движок ModX

Tags: mysql, modx

В БД ModX REVO создана таблица, куда ежедневно добавляется информация, структура - `id+text+адрес` сохраненной на сервере картинки.

Сделал сниппет с банальным запросом к этой таблице, через `$query = $modx->query($sql);`  и дальше циклом `while` вывожу каждую строку в виде списка.  Но это все на **одной** странице, где через шаблон добавлен этот сниппет.

А как теперь сделать пагинацию, используя возможности ModX? Всякие TV и прочая не нужны. Создавать автоматом для каждой строки ресурс (статью) считаю как минимум неразумно. Всего навсего вывести банальный список - id, строка текста, картинка.

Подскажите, кто как выходит из похожей ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать сниппет [pdoPage](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdopage). Он прекрасно может принимать в качестве параметра `&element` созданный вами сниппет.

Надо правда учитывать, что ваш сниппет должен дружить с параметрами `&page` и `&limit`.

Например  сниппет:

```
$q = $modx->newQuery("MyTableQuery");
$total = $modx->getCount("MyTableQuery", $q);

$totalVar = $modx->getOption('totalVar', $scriptProperties, 'total');
$modx->setPlaceholder($totalVar, $total);

$limit = $modx->getOption('limit', $scriptProperties, 20);
$offset = $modx->getOption('offset', $scriptProperties, 0);
$q->limit($limit, $offset);

$list = $modx->getCollection('MyTableQuery', $q);

foreach ($list as $k => $res) { ... // выводим, как требуется
```

И соответственно в нужном месте вызываем *pdoPage*:

```
<div id="pdopage">
    <div class="rows">
    [[!pdoPage?
           &element=`МойСниппет`
           &ajaxMode=`default`
           &limit=`20`
    ]]
    </div>
    [[!+page.nav]]
</div>
```

Comment: а если pdoTools не установлен, в смысле без него обойтись?

Comment: если он не установлен - то смысла не устанавливать его нет совсем - pdotools такая штука что нужна в любом проекте.

Comment: может быть PDO и полезная штука, Безумкина читал, проникся, но вот сейчас делаю простенький сервис для себя (анализ-статистика), от ModX использую только редактирование ПЯТИ страничек с текстом и все, остальное реализуется скриптами, коих в репозитарий естественно не нашлось... PDO не всегда полезен